# Variance Condition for Convergence in Probability against a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that $\mathbf E X_n$ converges to $\mu\in\mathbb R$ as $n\to\infty$. It follows directly from Chebyshef's inequality that the condition $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{Var}X_n=0$ implies the convergence of $X_n$ to $\mu$ in probability.

**Question:** Is this implication actually an equivalence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: Let $X_n$ take value $\sqrt n$ with probability $1/n$, and value $0$ otherwise. Then $E(X_n) = 1/\sqrt n\to0$. You can check that $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability. But ${\rm Var} (X_n)\to1$.